# File upload using Form-data is failing for retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, android, csv, file-upload, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a .csv file using Retrofit 2.
Below curl command is working well:

```
curl -X POST "<Base_URL>/upload" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Device-Id: abcd" 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@23May201811:16:17pm_data.csv;type=text/csv"
```

My implementation in Android is below:

```
@Multipart
@Headers({"accept: application/json"})
@POST("rawdata/insecured/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadRawFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Header("Device-Id") String header, @Part("description") RequestBody string);


RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/csv"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("csv", file.getName(), requestBody);
    RequestBody contentDescription = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, "FileName");
    Call<ResponseBody> apiCall = client.getApiService().uploadRawFile(body, device_Id, contentDescription);
```

And the Android log is:

```
07-03 23:30:27.240 14996-16885/bendmotionproj D/OkHttp: --> POST http://BaseUrl/upload http/1.1
07-03 23:30:27.241 14996-16885/bendmotionproj D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=3380e202-b5da-4fef-b287-d2f75e645400
07-03 23:30:27.243 14996-16885/bendmotionproj D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 12699
    accept: application/json
    Device-Id: 9bea6afdd252682a
07-03 23:30:27.249 14996-16885/bendmotionproj D/OkHttp: --3380e202-b5da-4fef-b287-d2f75e645400
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csvfile"; filename="Jul3,201811:30:25PM_data.csv"
    Content-Type: text/csv
    Content-Length: 12269
    Sensor Address,Timestamp (S),Fused Angle,Flex Angle,Perp. Angle
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.0,-42.2,-36.4,7.1
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.05,-37.5,-33.2,3.6
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.1,-34.4,-30.9,0.6
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.15000000000000002,-32.5,-29.2,-2.7
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.2,-32.5,-29.2,-5.4
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.25,-29.4,-25.9,-7.0
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.30000000000000004,-26.5,-23.6,-7.0
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.35000000000000003,-22.8,-21.1,-4.3
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.4,-21.1,-21.1,-1.7
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.45,-21.1,-21.1,0.1
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.5,-21.1,-21.1,0.1
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.55,-23.9,-21.1,2.0
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.6000000000000001,-28.7,-26.1,2.0
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.65,-38.2,-33.8,2.0
    C6:25:44:AF:CB:CD,0.7000000000000001,-53.2,-45.6,5.5
07-03 23:30:28.539 14996-16885/bendmotionproj D/OkHttp: <-- 400  http://BaseURL/upload (1280ms)
    X-Application-Context: kinexcsapigateway:with-service-discovery:8080
    Date: Tue, 03 Jul 2018 15:30:23 GMT
    Content-Length: 0
    Connection: close
    <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
07-03 23:30:28.555 14996-14996/bendmotionproj D/BaseResponse: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=, url=http://BaseUrl/upload}
07-03 23:30:28.560 14996-14996/bendmotionproj D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
```

The network response is 400. And even the API call is not hitting server. The missing part is to properly designate form-data in retrofit request for file. I need to know how to use -F for file upload. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);`

to

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/csv"), file);
```

If the mime type is wrong, find mime type  using

```
mimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("csv");
        Log.e("mime:", mimeType);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Updating question with your comments.
Still after updating mime-type in code I am getting 400 error code from server.

Comment: Is this your full log? There's no log showing upload of the bytes. That means there may be problems with the file.

Comment: This isn't full logs. I added some part of the log where csv file was read. and logged the data. Updated the logs.